# Requirement to Divorce an Infertile Wife or Marry a Second Wife

Tags: rambam, children-parenting, divorce, rishonim, polygamy

In the Mishneh Torah [הלכות אישות פרק טו, ב](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/4115.htm#8) Rambam requires a man to who hasn't had a male and female child and whose wife has not given birth for ten years since their marriage to either take a second wife for the purpose of fulfilling "be fruitful and multiply" or divorce the wife.

Do other Rishonim list this or a similar requirement, or is it only Rambam?  If other Rishonim discuss it, what do they say?

Comment: Its a machlokes if it applies only in Eretz Yisrael

Comment: Of course they do! They Rambam (usually) doesn't make stuff up, this rule is in the Mishnah (Yevamos 64a) and is therefore quoted by the Rif and Rosh there

Answer (score 3):

Others discuss the braisa in Yevamos 64a which is the source of the Rambam. See tosafos there d.h. af al pi. See also in maseches Ksuvos 77a tos. d.h. lisni.
See also the Tur in Even Ha'ezer siman 1 siff 3 with Darkei Moshe And Shulchan Aruch with Ramma there in the name of shu't Rivash siman 15 who says we no longer enforce this.

Comment: If you could summarize a bit of what they say it would make this answer much better.

Comment: @Robert I can try to later, but just for the record your question only asked for who discusses it, not what they say.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to reflect that.  All, I'm primarily interested in the opinions of Rishonim.

Comment: @Robert alright. The Rivash is definitely a rishon. I only brought the achronim quoting him for ease of accessibility.